# Side vertical menu to always stay in a fixed position after appearing

Tags: css, css-position

I have a side menu that appears when you click on an icon. It goes from being 100% to the left, to being just 70%, so it becomes visible. My problem is that when I resize the page horizontally the menu moves around, I need it to always be at the same place relative to the window I suppose, but it has to be fixed because I want the elements in the menu to remain in sight if the user scroll vertically...

You can see an example here:

https://codepen.io/SergiOca/pen/bWddxN

If you resize the window to for example, 1250px, that's how I'd like it to stay no matter how the user would resize the window.

**HTML**

```
                <div class="nav-menu"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li class="list-item-main"> <span> <a href="#"> Sobre nosotros. </a> </span> </li>
                        <li class="list-item-main"> <span> <a href="#"> Real estate. </a> </span> 
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Oferta </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Venta </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Colaboración </a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-item-main"> <span> <a href="#"> Consulting. </a></span> 
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Import/Export </a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-item-main"> <span> <a href="#"> Contacto. </span> </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-menu{
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 430px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 400;
    top: 0%;
    padding: 160px 65px;
    transition: ease-in-out 500ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.43, 1.19);
```

}

**JS:**

```
$(".nav-hamburger").on("click", function(){

    if($(".nav-menu").hasClass("active-menu")){
      $(".nav-menu").css("left", "100%");
      $(".nav-menu").removeClass("active-menu");
      $(".cross-icon").fadeOut();
      $(".hamburger-icon").fadeIn();

    } else {


    $(".nav-menu").css("left", "70%");
    $(".nav-menu").addClass("active-menu");
    $(".hamburger-icon").fadeOut();
    $(".cross-icon").fadeIn();
  }

})
```

Comment: Try using `right:-430px` and `right:0` instead. Using % may be causing the browser to recalculate each time.

Comment: 5 seconds before reading this I tried right: 0 and that's what I need. Thank you.